# Add DOCTYPE to generated download file from extracted div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, doctype

**Issue:** Trying to build a valid html file download based off div content on page, but I cannot get the content wrapped in the proper tags.

**Question:** How can I add the `!DOCTYPE`, `<head></head>` and `<html></html>` tags to a file download built from extracted div content?

I cannot add these tags within the div because the DOM doesn't recognize the duplicates.

Current code: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xs01zv5/5/)

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/html';
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();
}
var fileName = 'filename.html';

$('#download').click(function () {
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'downloadCode', 'text/html');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the wrapper data after you extract the contents from the div?

```
var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
var fullHtml = "<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>" + elHtml + "</body></html>"
```

Since this is string handling instead of DOM manipulation you can basically do whatever you want.